# how to resend a mailing to corrected bounce addresses?

Tags: civimail

so i did a mailing, a handful of bounces on a vip group, so we took the time to find why the email addresses were invalid and fixed them.

How can we resent this email to the corrected emails? I did try to clone the mailing and exclude the ones that received the previous one, but civi is removing all the contacts, even those that didn't receive it.

Comment: I had the same problem. Why is this not considered a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Adv Search you can select the 'bounced' contacts for that specific mailing and then add them to a new group (or not) and fire a new Mailing off to them

Comment: aah, i'm fighting already with tons of temp groups, but smart workaround, i almost like it...

Comment: so maybe a +.06 or +.07 - and then just round it up?